# writing a matrix to a file, without a header and row numbers

Tags: file, r, load

I have a matrix variable in R, say k. I want to write it out as a file. I use the code like:

```
write.table(k,file="outfile",sep="\t")
```

But when I get the file and open it, it contains headers. The first line is like: "v1"  "v2" ...... "V6000". And after that, each line starts with the row number like "1","2" and so on. I don't want headers. Is there a way to do that?

And now I even cannot load the file into R again using `read.table("outfile",header=TRUE,sep= "\t")`, it's even not the same as what I previously outputed. R recognised the first colunm in the file which are row numbers as a new column.

Comment: Did you read `?write.table`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To remove row names and column names (header) when outputting a table to a text file, assign `FALSE` to both `row.names` and `col.names` when writing the matrix,

```
m <- matrix(1:12, 4 , 3)
write.table(m, file="outfile,txt", sep="\t", col.names = F, row.names = F)
```

Comment: Oh, I only know header=FALSE, when I tried that in write.table, it says error. So I have to use col.names and row.names separatly. Thanks.

Comment: @lolibility, do you know about R's help feature? If not you should try writing `?write.table` into your R console and then press enter.

Comment: I used the write.table help and still came here in hopes of further clarification.